# IIS Logs not getting created

Tags: iis, iis-6, log-files

I have a site running on IIS 6. I have turned on logging on the website tab of IIS and specified a directory for it to write to. Set it to an hourly schedule.

However no logs are ever created.

Have reset iis. checked disk space and permissions on the directory it is writing to but no logs are ever created.
I can see this did work once, as there are logs created in the system32/logfiles directory from about a year ago. Even if I specify that directory nothing new gets created

This is on a hosted service

What else can I check?
Is there any place that errors would be written to that might give me a clue as to what is going on? Have tried event viewer but nothing untoward in there

Would appreciate any pointers on this

Comment: I have the same issue. Was in the process of asking the same question and found yours. Alas, no answers!

Answer (score 1):

Logs don't get created unless there's actually activity on the site in question (visits to the site). Do you know if the site has been visited since you turned on logging?

Comment: yes, there is constant activity on the site. Generated by both myself and the site users.
When I try this on my dev machine the directory in the logfile dir is created straight away.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Don’t see enough log in IIS logfiles](http://blogs.msdn.com/vivekkum/archive/2008/12/28/don-t-see-enough-log-in-iis-logfiles.aspx).